# Связь Excel и андроид приложения

Tags: android, excel

Не знаю, правильно обозвал или нет, надеялся донести идею, как она есть в прекрасном работающем виде в моей голове)

**Что имеется:**

Таблица в Excel, там данные
1) номер услуги(заказа, или кому как удобнее, мы оказываем услуги по ремонту, все пишем в таблицу)
2) модель, тип товара - телефон, телевизор и так далее...
3) телефон клиента
4) дата
5) цена
и там далее итог, и некоторые уточнения - пароль от телефона если он есть или, комментарий.. Не так важно думаю

Есть телефон, с которого мы все время звоним клиентам, по поводу ремонта- готов или нет. Ну и собственно приходится набирать ручками все это.
Хотелось бы как то сделать проще и быстрее - нажал и звонок идет.

**Идеи которые есть** :

1) Приложение на андроид - написать приложение которое будет связываться с таблицей( я даже не знаю каким образом, я просто это пока представляю),брать оттуда, для начала, последние сегодняшние номера( по ним звоним чаще всего) и показывать их, с краткой инфой. Ну и чтобы редактировать можно было( не не, не показывать всю эту таблицу, там 9к записей, думаю телефон с приложением зависнет надолго.)
2) GappScript - через скрипты гугла и может быть гугл таблицы получать данные и звонить - вроде бы там есть и доступ к контактам.

Это находится в одном офисе, поэтому я думаю сервер можно поставить на том же компе, если он нужен.

Ну и в соответствии с этим у меня куча вопросов:
Правильно ли я копаю, в том ли направлении, не делаю велосипед?
Нет, платных сервисов, где можно все это онлайн делать - **не нужно**, да и не интересно, хочется что то сделать своими ручками. Тем более это все нужно переносить, работникам привыкать.
Быстрее ли гугл таблицы чем обычные что на компе, с таким кол-вом записей?
Ну и как вообще связать телефон с Excel ? С помощью запросов, сервера? или есть еще какие то способы? Что почитать хотя бы на эту тему, потому что правильно сформулировать вопрос в гугл и яндекс я не смог, не нашел тех ответов, что интересовали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверенное надёжное решение - БД с REST API на сервере и приложение на стороне Android. Всё остальное, что Вы предлагаете - велосипеды и костыли.

С хранилищем данных на основе Excel Вам будет крайне сложно реализовать даже часть функционала, особенно если учесть, что Excel для таких вещей и не предназначен.

Возьмите любую серверную СУБД и сделайте для неё API на любом из "серверных" языков, который знаете. Далее по этому API Вы без особого труда построите взаимодействие между сервером и Android и будет Вам счастье.

> Тем более это все нужно переносить, работникам привыкать.

Рано или поздно всё меняется. На первых порах может будет нелегко. Но, если качественно разработаете ПО удобство и скорость работы быстро компенсируют издержки переходного периода и о своих "мучениях" пользователи вскоре забудут.

> там 9к записей
>
> . . .
>
> Быстрее ли гугл таблицы чем обычные что на компе, с таким кол-вом
>   записей?

При большом количестве записей эффективнее всего СУБД, а не велосипеды на таблицах.